# How to get node by name?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

It's a simple task, but I can't make it work. Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
    <item1></item1>
    <item2></item2>
    <item3></item3>
</product>
```

I'd like to get all nodes within `product`. Following two attempts return no nodes, I don't see why:

```
XDocument meteoDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
foreach (var item in meteoDoc.Descendants("product")) {//...}
foreach (var item in meteoDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "product").Nodes()) {//...}
```

The following, as expected, would return me all nodes:

```
foreach (var item in meteoDoc.DescendantNodes()) { //...}
```

Thx for any tipps, I can't see the problem... :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt is asking for all the `Descendants` *called* `product`. Your second attempt is finding the direct child nodes of all descendants called `product`.

It's possible that it's looking for descendants *within* the root element... if you know that the root element is called `product`, you could just use:

```
foreach (var item in meteoDoc.Root.Descendants())
```

(I can't test your existing code to find out exactly why it's not working for you right now, I'm afraid.)

Note that `Descendants` will only find descendant *elements* - if you want all descendant *nodes*, you need the [`DescendantNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes.aspx) method.

Comment: Yeah, product is actually the root in this case, works fine like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
XDocument meteoDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
foreach (var item in meteoDoc.Root.Descendants())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        foreach (var item in meteoDoc.Descendants("product"))
        {
            foreach (var prod in item.Descendants())
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few change to xml, in this way the data is more well-formed and i can give you a piece of code that accomplish your task.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Data.xml
        /*
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <product>
                <item>
                    <name>test</name>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>test2</name>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>test3</name>
                </item>
            </product>
         */


        XDocument meteoDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

        var result = from c in meteoDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new { Name = c.Element("name").Value };

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
```

Comment: I have no influence in the data I described since it is delivered from a 3th party. thx anyway.